# Liferay: No Layout exists with the primary key 0

Tags: java, content-management-system, liferay, velocity, portal

I am having troubles with my Liferay-Portal after I included a function to generate the friendly URL. This is the function:

```
#set ($layoutLocalService = $serviceLocator.findService("com.liferay.portal.service.LayoutLocalService"))
#set ($layoutId = $getterUtil.getLong($image-link.getData()))
#set ($themeDisplay = $request.get('theme-display'))
#set ($currentPlid = $getterUtil.getLong($themeDisplay.get('plid')))
#set ($currentLayout = $layoutLocalService.getLayout($currentPlid))
#set ($layout = $layoutLocalService.getLayout($getterUtil.getLong($groupId), $currentLayout.isPrivateLayout(), $layoutId))
#set( $friendlyUrl = $layout.getFriendlyURL().replace("/", "") )
```

After a successful deployment, while surfing over the website my console outputs this:

```
09:15:26,279 ERROR [http-bio-8080-exec-83][LiferayMethodExceptionEventHandler:33] com.liferay.portal.NoSuchLayoutException: No Layout exists with the primary key 0
com.liferay.portal.NoSuchLayoutException: No Layout exists with the primary key 0
```

**How do I get the layoutID of the current page and not of that image link?**

Comment: Your `$layoutId` is initialized as `#set ($layoutId = $getterUtil.getLong($image-link.getData()))` - does this happen to be `0`?

Comment: That image didnt even exist. I copied the code of some sample page.

Comment: If this is within a template, the sample structure that was underlying the template, obviously had a field named image-link, which your structure doesn't have. Otherwise, please specify where you're using this velocity code. Also, it might help what you're trying to achieve, we might provide some hints on how to solve the underlying problem easier than solving the issue with the implementation path that you chose. Please rephrase the question with the underlying problem.

Comment: @OlafKock I rephrased my question. If there's a better way to implement this I'd be happy to hear about.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`$themeDisplay`](http://docs.liferay.com/portal/6.1/javadocs/com/liferay/portal/theme/ThemeDisplay.html) is your friend and might have everything that you're looking for (including the current layout (page). The javadoc I linked is not that great, but the methods you'll find there are mostly descriptive and should give you a clue what kind of current context you can get from this object.

e.g. in a Theme, you can use `$themeDisplay.getLayout().getRegularURL($request)` to get the current page